# How to create a anonymous link for the documents in Sharepoint Online 2018

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-2016

I am trying to create a anonymous link for the documents in Sharepoint online 2018.

I have tried using the CreateAnonymousLink method provided by Microsoft.SharePoint.Client but it throws error.

`ClientResult<string> result = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web.CreateAnonymousLink(clientContext, absoluteurl, false);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();`

Comment: What is the error it's throwing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Sample test code for your reference.

```
using (var context = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer"))
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                string password = "pw";
                SecureString sec_pass = new SecureString();
                Array.ForEach(password.ToArray(), sec_pass.AppendChar);
                sec_pass.MakeReadOnly();
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("lee@tenant.onmicrosoft.com", sec_pass);
                ClientResult<string> a = Web.CreateAnonymousLink((ClientRuntimeContext)context, "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer/Shared%20Documents/Culture%20Training.docx", false);

                context.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("done");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

[image]